# sentence correction - has/have

Tags: grammar

The recent technological advances have generated different effects for clerical workers (high school graduates) and workers with advanced degrees.

Should one use have or has before generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is "The recent technological advances", which is a plural noun, and means you should use "have".